# Dynamically Added Property Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I am reading in some external JSON data and then trying to amend it a bit by adding a custom property about whether or not the item is checked. The `isChecked` property does not exist in the external data.

I am adding the property and value as follows:

```
this.props.information.options[optionId].isChecked = true;
```

The problem is, when I later iterate through the `options` array, the `isChecked` property always returns `undefined`:

```
this.props.information.options.forEach((option, index) => {
  //Check if it should be checked
  var ministry = this.props.information.name;

  console.log(option); //outputs object with isChecked property (see screenshot)

  if (option.isChecked !== undefined) {
    isChecked = option.isChecked;
  }
  else {
    console.log(option["isChecked"]); //Always outputs undefined
  }
}
```

So I'm really confused. Firefox is showing the property as part of the object, but then returning it as `undefined` no matter if I use the . or [] notation.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You have the same behaviour in Chrome?

Comment: is `option.isChecked` defined?

Comment: Are you adding the property in a callback from an asynchronous call?

Comment: of course it will always throw undefined since you're in the else condition :D anyway, have you tried other properties?

Comment: @Roljhon I think you're right. It outputs as `undefined` for the options whose `isChecked` is never set. @EricRovtar try to put the `console.log(option["isChecked"]);` outiside the `else` to see if they're all outputs as `undefined`.

Comment: @Roljhon Yes. Sorry. I see what you're saying, but if you look at my screenshot, there are four objects, the first two have isChecked set to true. You're seeing the properties of the first below the console log.

Comment: @Roljhon And yes, other properties test just fine.

Comment: @EricRovtar did the below answer didn't fix your issue?

Comment: @Roljhon Yes, see my comments below. Same results as above. I can see the object having an `isChecked` property and that property set to `true`, but whenever I test for it, it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect. You should be checking if `isChecked` *is* defined. Better yet, check if it is strictly equal to the expected value.

```js
var options = [{}, {}, {}];
options[0].isChecked = true;

options.forEach(function(option, index) {
  if (option.isChecked === true) {
    console.log('checked');
  } else {
    console.log('not checked');
  }
});
```

Comment: I tired that, but still am getting `undefined`. The object shows it has `isChecked: true` when I browse it in the console, but then it doesn't test positive for being `true` and outputs `undefinted`.

Comment: @EricRovtar would it be possible to post your full example to a fiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry. The script wasn't compiling. Testing for true does fix the issue. Sorry about that. Thanks, Max!